# Why Execution Properties can not return project.version?

Tags: maven, maven-plugin

I am developing a custom Maven plugin and I read some files. There are some variables that defined as

```
${foo}
```

and if there were at pom, maven could understand its value. I have to understand its value too. I found that:

```
/**
* @parameter expression="${session}"
*/
private MavenSession session;
...
session.getExecutionProperties()
```

When I say it I get many properties but when I say:

```
session.getExecutionProperties().getProperty("project.version")
```

it returns me null. What does execution properties returns(does it include system properties and JVM properties) and why it doesn't understand something like

> ${project.version}

**what should I do to get the values of something like it?**

**PS:** My question is not how can I get project.version, it is just an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have implemented a Interpolator with an interceptor and could get values of Maven variables.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the following:

```
/**
 * The Maven Project Object
 *
 * @parameter expression="${project}"
 * @required
 * @readonly
 */
protected MavenProject project;

...

project.getVersion();
```